# How can I modify the .buildpath file in my Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt, dltk

I have written a plugin that uses PDT (and thus DLTK) to create a customized project. I now to need to add libraries to the buildpath of my custom project.

I do have a plugin that contains these libraries and I've been struggling trying to figure out how to create / modify the .buildpath file. I was not successful trying to use BuildpathEntry, as it seemed to fail because the path I provided to .buildpath did not contain a device id.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

**EDIT**: I'm trying to add PHP libraries to the .buildpath file of my PDT project in my custom plugin, just to be clear ;)

Comment: Have you tried expressing a dependency from your PDT plug-in to the plug-in that contains those libraries? Ie in plugin.xml

Comment: The libraries are PHP libraries (eg: Zend Framework), not java ones, so I can't create a dependency there.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with the `addEntriesToBuildPath` method of `org.eclipse.php.internal.core.buildpath.BuildPathUtils`.

1. Add `org.eclipse.php.core` and `org.eclipse.dltk.core` to the dependencies of your plugin.xml. (you have need installed PDT SDK)
2. Add the build path entry when create the project:

   ```
   IScriptProject scriptProject = DLTKCore.create(project);
   List<IBuildpathEntry> bentries = new ArrayList<IBuildpathEntry>();
   IBuildpathEntry juliaServerEntry = DLTKCore.newProjectEntry(new Path("/otherproject"));
   bentries.add(juliaServerEntry);
   BuildPathUtils.addEntriesToBuildPath(scriptProject, bentries);
   ```